# I want to make an API call that only returns unique results given a certain table field into my React frontend

Tags: sql, reactjs, api, flask

I'm trying to make an online shoe store using Flask as my backend and React as my frontend. I'm making API calls in my React app to the Flask backend which returns all of the data inside my 'shoes' table. The table includes elements such as brand, size, price, color, model, etc.

I'm able to retrieve all the data from the table by using useEffect:

```
function App() {

  // const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(); 
  const [shoes, setShoes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/shoes').then(response => 
      response.json().then(data => {
        setShoes(data.shoes);
      })
      );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="section">
        <h1 class="title">HI</h1>
        <Shoes shoes={shoes}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I would like to do the same, but only for unique model results, like if I have multiple shoes of the same model, only return it once. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove duplicates from your response. You can use javascript `Map` constructor for this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/shoes').then((response) =>
      response.json().then((data) => {
        const uniqueData = [...new Map(yourArray.map(item => [item['model'], item])).values()]
        console.log('uniqueData', uniqueData)
        setShoes(uniqueData)
      })
    )
  }, [])
```

In above code, the inner map will return an array of arrays with 2 items in it. The first item is key and 2nd item is the whole object.

With `new Map...`, it will return an object with key value pairs.

`.values()` will give just the values which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing my Flask API query to a distinct call instead of returning all shoes.